# Examples of modules over a group ring

Tags: modules, representation-theory

I am in search of some examples of *finite groups $G$* and modules over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ with following conditions (and examples taken independently). I do not have idea whether such examples are possible, and the question can be very trivial; but I didn't immediately get example(s) to justify some statements in an introduction to integral representations in Curtis-Reiner's representation theory book.

1) Finite group $G$ and a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module $M$ such that $M$ has no composition series. [This implies that Jordan-Holder theorem do not hold for $M$; am I right?]

2) Finite group $G$ and a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module $M$ such that Krull-Schmidt theorem fails for $M$.

3) Finite group $G$ and a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module $M$ such that $M$ contains a proper non-zero $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-submodule but has no complement (i.e. that submodule is not a direct summand).

---

If $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by a field $K$ whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$ then above examples are not possible- standard beginning of representation theory of groups. But  Curtis-Reiner says that such results (Jordan-Holder/ Krull-Schmidt/ Maschke's theorem) are no longer true if the field $K$ is replaced by a ring $R$. In this regard, I was looking for simple examples for failure.

Comment: Are you happy with examples where $|G|=1$?

Comment: No; I am sorry for not mentioning this explicitly in the question. Should I edit?

Comment: Well, if you have examples where $|G|=1$, you can turn them into examples over any nontrivial group $G$ by just letting $G$ act trivially.